# What should io.Write returns?

Tags: go, io, slice

I was learning go and doing some tests with the language when I found this weird behavior in my code. I create two types to demonstrate my findings and implemented the interface `io.Write` on both. This little program downloads the content of a web page and prints it to the console.
The `BrokenConsoleWriter` keeps track of the bytes written by `fmt.Println` and any error it may "throw" and returns it. On the other hand, the `ConsoleWriter` simply ignore the return of `fmt.Println` and returns the total length of the slice and nil for the error.

When I run the program, the `BrokenConsoleWriter` doesn't print the entire html content while that `ConsoleWriter` does. Why is this happening?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

type ConsoleWriter struct{}
type BrokenConsoleWriter struct{}

func (b BrokenConsoleWriter) Write(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    bytesWritten, error := fmt.Println(string(p))
    return bytesWritten, error
}

func (c ConsoleWriter) Write(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    fmt.Println(string(p))
    return len(p), nil
}

func main() {
    const url = "https://www.nytimes.com/"
    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Some error occurred:", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    //io.Copy(ConsoleWriter{}, resp.Body)
    io.Copy(BrokenConsoleWriter{}, resp.Body)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Write()` method is to implement [`io.Write()`](https://pkg.go.dev/io#Writer) which documents that:

> Write writes len(p) bytes from p to the underlying data stream. **It returns the number of bytes written from p (0 <= n <= len(p))** and any error encountered that caused the write to stop early. Write must return a non-nil error if it returns n < len(p). Write must not modify the slice data, even temporarily.
>
> Implementations must not retain p.

So your `Write()` method must report how many bytes you processed from the `p` slice passed to you. Not how many bytes you generate to some other source.

And this is the error with your `BrokenConsoleWriter.Write()` implementation: you don't report how many bytes you process from `p`, you report how many bytes [`fmt.Prinln()`](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#Println) actually writes. And since `fmt.Prinln()` also prints a newline after printing its arguments, the value it returns will surely be not valid for `BrokenConsoleWriter.Write()`.

Note that `fmt.Prinln()` with a single `string` argument will write out that string and append a newline, which on unix systems is a single character `\n`, and `\r\n` on Windows. So on unix systems you also get a correct behavior if you subtract `1` from its return value:

```
func (b BrokenConsoleWriter) Write(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    bytesWritten, error := fmt.Println(string(p))
    return bytesWritten - 1, error
}
```

Also note that the input is already formatted into lines, so you inserting newlines "randomly" by using `fmt.Prinln()` may even result in an invalid document. Do use [`fmt.Print()`](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#Print) instead of `fmt.Println()`:

```
func (b BrokenConsoleWriter) Write(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    bytesWritten, error := fmt.Print(string(p))
    return bytesWritten, error
}
```

But the correctness of this solution still depends on the implementation of `fmt.Print()`. The correct solution is to report `len(p)` because that's what happened: you processed `len(p)` bytes of the input slice (all of it).

Comment: but the `fmt.Println` states that "It returns the number of bytes written and any write error encountered." So, shouldn't it works? I understand that the correctness depends on the fmt.Println but it seems to be correct... Why subtracting -1 works but if I hardcode, let's say 20, it doesn't ?

Comment: @BrunoCasarotti Because if a slice with 10 bytes is handed to you, you have to report how many bytes you processed out of those 10. Using `fmt.Prinln()`, it will print those 10 bytes plus a newline, so `fmt.Prinln()` will report it has written 11 bytes. From your `Write()` you can't report you processed 11 bytes out of 10 bytes!

Comment: If a slice has 100 bytes and in my Write function I always report 1, should it be called again by io.Copy? I am just experimenting with it to understand what is happening

Comment: @BrunoCasarotti You must adhere to the "contract" of `io.Writer`, which I even quoted in my answer, please read it carefully: _"Write must return a non-nil error if it returns n < len(p)."_ So if 100 bytes are handed to you and you return `1`, you also have to return a non-`nil` error, in which case `io.Copy()` will hand you the remaining 99 bytes again. If you don't adhere to the contract, you can't expect anything, then you have no guarantee what will or will not happen. What actually happens is implementation dependent and may change from version to version, from platform to platform.

Comment: @BrunoCasarotti, I find it helpful to have a useful mental model to understand this contract. A good one is writing a file when the underlying storage space fills up. Say, your program calls `*os.File.Write` (which is an `io.Writer`) telling it to write 1000 bytes of data. The Writer manages to save 500 and detects there's no more space left on the disk drive, and so it tells the calling program it _has managed to save_ 500 bytes but the rest left unprocessed…

Comment: @BrunoCasarotti, …now the program could report that to the user and waits to hear back, the user deletes some unneeded files freeing up the storage space, tells the program that it could try to continue and then your program tries to write _those unprocessed 500 bytes_ from the original slice in a new call to `Write` on the same `*os.File`, which is now likely to succeed. `io.Copy` does not have such "report then wait then retry" logic because that'd be overengineering but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: @BrunoCasarotti, you may also look at this from another PoV: the Go's contracts of `io.Reader.Read` and `io.Writer.Write` reflect 1-to-1 the established contracts of the OS kernels implemented in their system calls which allow to read data from "resources providing data streams" and write to them (see https://manpages.debian.org/2/write for a start). For instance, when writing to a network socket it's useful to accept from the client just as much data which fits the internal socket buffer and report that "it's all for now" and the client should come later attempting to write the rest.